# Moving bitcoins around

Tags: bitcoin-core, mining-theory, mining-reward

I am doing some reading about bitcoin and my understanding is that miners get 25 BTC for every transaction that is made. This means that even for a transaction of 0.01 BTC 25 will be generated. Doesn't this mean that people will be able to create a lot of low valued transactions (constantly moving btc around) to generate more and more bitcoins?

Comment: No, you're confusing *block reward* (currently 12.5 BTC) with *transaction fees* (which are much smaller).

Comment: Ok blocks store transaction data right? so the number of transactions still affect the blocks. So doesn't that mean still that more transactions = more blocks?

Comment: Sounds like you've got some more reading to do. Blocks are found every 10 minutes *on average*. A typical block today might contain 2500 transactions or so.

Answer (score 1):

The miner gets a reward of 12.5 bitcoins plus transaction fees every block, not every transaction.  Blocks occur approximately every 10 minutes, and the reward is cut in half approximately every 4 years.